# Reading Dentrix G4 data into dot.net application

Tags: c#, .net, dentrix

I am searching for a way to read data from Dentrix G4 into a windows form application. There is not much info on this over the web & I am not sure if this is possible. Has anyone been able to parse dentrix g4 data to another application?

***Thanks***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first like to introduce myself (per moderator request) as a Dentrix Developer Partner. I do not work for Dentrix, I'm an authorized 3rd-party Dentrix developer. I also like to state very clear that is not my intention to get any profit out of the information I like to share with you.

Reading data from a Dentrix G4 database or older versions is really complicated and is not officially supported by Dentrix. You can possibly manage yourself by using an Hex Editor or something, but you really have no way to do it with an API or an SDK since Dentrix doesn't provide those for G4 and older versions. On top of that, using any method of reading the database without Dentrix's approval could fall into a HIPAA violation and you could get yourself in real trouble.

When Dentrix G5 came out early in 2012 they implemented encryption to the database itself so at this point a Hex Editor would be out of the question, but not everything is lost.

With Dentrix G5 (and higher) the database structure changed again, but this time for good. Dentrix G5 finally uses an SQL database engine that allows you to query the data in a much easier way.

The engine they use is ctreeACE SQL developed by Faircom.

Much better, they now provide APIs and SDKs for developing purposes which allows you full access to the database in read-only mode and in some cases, limited-write access.

If you like to get a hold on an API, I recommend you to go to http://ddp.dentrix.com for more information.

Once again, I like to state very clear is not my intention to get any compensation from sharing this out since I don't get any benefit from it anyways. Reason for this is the API implies a cost (is not free).

I truly hope you find this information useful.

Good luck.

Comment: This thread is pretty old now but I have a question that with developer license will I be able to connect to local Dentrix database (6.2 and above)?

Comment: Sorry I barely saw this.
I just checked and Dentrix still provides an API that works even on newer versions released after my original post, or in other words, Dentrix G6.x and Dentrix G7.x

Comment: Just so everyone is aware, the only non-hacky way to connect to Dentrix is through their "developer program" which Schein uses as a revenue stream.  Patterson does the same.  Both companies have worked very hard to prevent offices from getting at their own data in the formats they want without using a 3rd-party vendor.  Costs can be several hundred dollars *per month* *per office* you want to connect to.  We are working diligently to migrate everyone away from the vendor lock-in Schein and Patterson are trying to create.